# Can we say 'it seems needn't do that'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I don't know why I thought of that sentence. I was about to comment someone's post and one phrase that came from my mind was that.

Anyway, if my guess is correct, isn't **seem** a linking verb? I'm not sure if it needs **to** to put after that or not, but can we say:

> It seems needn't do that.

I was about to use the modal verb **need**. I don't know why if you ask me why I think it's incorrect. The problem of my doubt is the modal that's placed after the linking verb. If this is incorrect, can you suggest the appropriate phrase?

Comment: With *It **seems** you need help*, if we want to remove that implication of "apparently, perhaps" we just discard both the "dummy" ***it*** and the verb ***seems*** (nothing else changes). But with *You **seem** to need help*, when we remove ***seem*** we have to convert infinitive ***to need*** into a "tensed" second person singular verb form: *You **need** help*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ungrammatical.

The verb "seem" can link to a complement that could be a noun, adjective or even an infinitive phrase:

> She seems to need a cup of coffee.

but the infinitive must be a "to" infinitive.  It would be grammatically correct to chain infinitives together like this:

> It seems not to need to do that.

But in a specific context, there is probably a simpler way of expressing that idea.

Answer (score 3):

**Needn't** is a contraction of "need not" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/needn-t)).

With that in mind, your sentence makes sense if you include a pronoun:

> It seems (that) **you / he / they** *need not* do that.

Seem does not change the sentence.

> **You / He / They** *need not* do that.

"[you] **need not** do [that]" is the same as saying "[you] **don't need to** do [that]".